# Is there an npm module to modify a pdf file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ibm-cloud, node-modules

I'm building a node.js app on Bluemix that should take a pdf file as request and then grey out (blank) some part of the pdf file. And also here the pdf file is the same for all, and the area we need to blank out will be fixed. So can anybody suggest an npm module that can perform this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 7):

Yes I guess the most common used library is [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib). Take a look at the [official page](https://pdf-lib.js.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [HummusPDF](http://pdfhummus.com).  Specifically take a look at the [Hummus - Modification](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Modification) page, that explains how to edit existing PDF documents. In your case you could try to use the feature that allows to [draw shapes](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Show-primitives).

Comment: Thanks.But I was not able to install hummus modulegyp
Getting some list of errors
 npm ERR! hummus@1.0.60 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hummus package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!   npm bugs hummus
npm ERR!  npm owner ls hummus
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Can u have a look on this module and suggest me if am doing some thing wrong

Comment: @HVarma Do you have any build tools installed? Node-gyp will try to run a C++ compiler to compile C++ code. If you don't have a C++ compiler installed node-gyp will fail

Comment: @HVarma See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp on how to get node to compile C++ modules on your OS

Answer (score -6):

Please try Aspose.PDF Cloud SDK for Node.js available at [GitHub](https://github.com/aspose-pdf-cloud/aspose-pdf-cloud-node.js) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asposepdfcloud). It provides API methods for a wide range of document processing operations; including creation, manipulation, conversion and rendering of Pdf documents in the cloud. You can use [Redaction Annotation](https://github.com/aspose-pdf-cloud/aspose-pdf-cloud-node.js/blob/master/test/testRedactionAnnotations.ts) to grey out the required PDF area.

P.S: I work with Aspose as Support Developer

Comment: This apparently requires a (paid?) account, so it's not processing the data locally at all.

Comment: Yes, it is paid REST API and free trial version provides 150 free credits monthly.