# How to convert PNG images to pdf using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, png

I was searching for NPM package which could help me to combine and convert multiple PNG images into pdf format. However I could only find pdf to png conversion packages not the other way around.

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=png%20to%20pdf&page=1&ranking=optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately I've started using imagemagic, it's pretty fast. There's a node package for imagemagic available out there although I haven't tried it yet.

[Imagemagic official website link](http://imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

PDF is just a document format. You can eventually add new image. Look, here is a simillar question.
[Is there an npm module to modify a pdf file in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362845/is-there-an-npm-module-to-modify-a-pdf-file-in-node-js)

And the first link from this topic https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake#images